# json_encode putting empty array on the end of json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm writing an ajax application and have a function in a php script:

```
public function expire_user() {
    $r=array("return"=>'OK');
    echo json_encode($r); 
}
```

that gets called with this javascript:

```
$.getJSON("/users/expire_user",function(data){
        alert('success');
});
```

The problem is that the alert never displays. I think this is due to json_encode returning invalid json, because when I go to the url directly, it displays

```
{"return":"OK"}[]
```

which is not valid json due to the extra '[]' on the end. Why is json_encode putting the empty array on the end and how do I get rid of it so that I can receive valid json?

Comment: Can we see how `expire_user` is called from `GET /users/expire_user`?  I bet it will work if you kill the script right away: `die(json_encode($r));`

Comment: don't think its a duplicate because Sam's comment worked for me and that wasn't in the other answer. @Sam post your code as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @JakeGould I was actually asking OP for more information, since the `[]` is returned by nothing in his shown code (i.e. what calls `expire_user()`.  I was proving this by the `die()` example.  I ***do not*** think this is a production-worthy use.

Comment: @JakeGould according to OP's comment on my answer that was the case.

Comment: The same thing happened to me, and I followed the execution sequence and my code was spitting an empty array in the next iteration of a loop when the input was empty. So I suspect the same could be in your case too, that somewhere your code is echoing empty array somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess, but maybe you should set correct headers for the JSON in your PHP function like this:

```
public function expire_user() {
    $r=array("return"=>'OK');
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($r); 
}
```

Or actually send the content as `X-JSON` headers like this:

```
public function expire_user() {
    $r=array("return"=>'OK');
    $json_data = json_encode($r);
    header('X-JSON: (' . $json_data . ')');
    header('Content-type: application/x-json');
    echo $json_data;
}
```

A bit rusty on whether when using `X-JSON` the accompanying header should be `application/x-json` or just the normal `application/json`, but adding this caveat to help you debug.

Comment: neither of those edits changed the output. There is still an empty array on the return

Comment: I didn't know about the headers though, that was very useful

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite an "answer", but I'm assuming your script is running some other code (maybe `echo json_encode(array());`) some time after `expire_user()` is called.  To ensure that this is the last thing called you can use [`die()`](https://www.php.net/die) or [`exit()`](https://www.php.net/exit):

```
public function expire_user() {
    $r = array("return"=>'OK');
    die(json_encode($r));
}
```

However, I suggest you try to debug the real problem.  For instance, if you have a URL router than is handling requests and calling methods..it could be errantly echoing extra characters (that may cause more problems down the line).  If you post your code that calls `expire_user()`, I can help debug further.

---

**Disclaimer:** I *do not* consider this a production-worthy solution. It needs more debugging, though.

Comment: Right again.. expire_users is actually a much longer function and I thought that those were the only two lines submitting output, but then I found an echo with an empty array somewhere towards the bottom when I checked again

Comment: Glad you were able to get to the bottom, I would not rely on `die()` then. It turns out to have been very helpful in debugging the problem though (`var_dump();` and `exit;` are my friends).

Comment: Comprehending documentation and efficiently debugging have been the two most important skills over the years that didn't just "come" to me . Thanks for the +1 @JakeGould